# Grabbing text data from Baseball-reference Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing

http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/split.cgi?id=aardsda01&year=2015&t=p

I would like to get the data of what arm this pitcher pitches with. If it were a table i would be able to grab the data but I dont know how to get the text.

```
David Aardsma    \ARDS-mah\

David Allan Aardsma (twitter: @TheDA53)

Position: Pitcher
Bats: Right, Throws: Right 
Height: 6' 3", Weight: 220 lb.
```

The text looks like this. I would like to get everything after `Throws:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to solve it with [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), you would find the `b` tag by text `Throws:` and get the [following sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> url = "http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/split.cgi?id=aardsda01&year=2015&t=p"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
>>> soup.find("b", text='Throws:').next_sibling.strip()
u'Right'
```

Comment: This is so clean! Well done.
For completeness, we need an 'import re' but maybe this is obvious

Comment: @JoeSparacino thanks, actually, we can use an exact match here, no need for `re`, edited.